# Pass main activity to outer class

Tags: android

I have a variable and I defined it in main activity.Like this:

```
public String TestVariable;
```

And I am setting the value of variable in `onCreate()` method and I have an outer class like this:

```
public class Connection {


     public void testMethod() {

         /*I have to access TestVariable from this method */
     }

}
```

I think I have to pass activity to this class but how ?

I am creating `Connection` class in `Application` class like this:

```
   private static Connection connection;

   public Connection getConnectionInstance() {
       if (connection == null)
           connection = new Connection();
       return connection;
   }
```

So I need help.How can I access the `TestVariable` from `Connection`

Answer (score 0):

```
//A very simple way to do it 
public class Connection {

public static  String testVariable=null;
   public void testMethod() {

         /*I have to access TestVariable from this method */
     }

}


// In the on create 
void onCreate ()
{
this.testVariable="hello world";
Connection.testVariable=this.testVariable;
}
```

this should work because as see it testVariable value is only set once and, and used after that

Comment: I would go with this solution, but instead of defining the testVariable of the Connection class, as public, I would set it protected or private and use a method, like setTestVariable. Doesn't need to be static, as you are using the connection class in kind of Singleton pattern.

Comment: yes, this could be applied to objects, And why do u need to send the main activity to the connection class , sometimes its not the activity object that you need its the context object for example...

Comment: I have to update testVariable from Connection class.